# Не работает recycle() у Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Ошибка java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.
Выяснил, что возникает из за большого количества фоток, загруженных в ImageView (всегда, после показа 93 фоток, приложение вылетает). Почему то не работает метод bitmap.recycle(). По идее он должен очистить память, и решить проблему.

```
Bitmap bm;

public void clickBtnNext(View v)
{
    if (bm != null)
    {
        bm.recycle();
        bm = null;
    }

    String photoName = photosList.get(counter);
    int photoID = getResources().getIdentifier(photoName, "drawable", getPackageName());

    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), photoID);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: По идее да, но как и где вы показываете ImageVIew? нужно иметь представление шире, если ошибка повторяется, значит проблема уже дальше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Все эти танци с бубном были ни к чему.
Для загрузки фоток лучше юзать библиотеку glide.

```
int photoID = getResources().getIdentifier("photo_name", "drawable", 
getPackageName());
Glide.with(this).load(photoID).into(mImageView);
```